# Cookie lost in the same host when iframe multi-level nesting

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, iframe, cross-domain

I try to nesting different iframe like this:

```html
<iframe src='http://test.com'></iframe>
```

`http://test.com` has document like this:

```html
<iframe src='http://test2.com'></iframe>
```

same as the test, `http://test2.com` has document like this:

```
<iframe src='http://test.com'></iframe>
```

now my html document just like this:

```
<iframe src='http://test.com'>
 <body>
   <iframe src='http://test2.com'>
     <body>
       <iframe src='http://test.com'>
       </iframe>
     </body>
   </iframe>
 </body>
</iframe>
```

Then I found my cookie lost in innermost iframe. I use to think it is worked because the iframe's src is the same. I understand iframe like a browser tab, why it can't share cookie?

Answer (score 0):

There have been numerous changes in Chrome (and other browsers) [regarding cookies and iframe.](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html)

It would seem like you need to set a `SameSite` directive on the cookie, as well as marking it as `HTTO-ONLY`. Additionally third-party cookies will only be served to `Secure` domains, so you maybe be able to complete this test by switching to https, and marking the cookie as `Secure`.

The basics of what is changing is there is now a 'SameSite' cookie policy, where `Only cookies set as SameSite=None; Secure will be available in third-party contexts, provided they are being accessed from secure connections.` So marking the cookies as `Secure` and `HTTP-Only` is a must in addition to the `SameSite=None`

Also in Safari, the third-party frame will have to request access to the [storage API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/) before the cookie will be accessible.

Firefox is using a partitioned approach to the storage, and so the frame will behave as normal unless you then open your application as a new window then the cookie store may or may not follow depending on how the new window was created.

[Cookie Status](https://www.cookiestatus.com/) is an excellent resource to track how third party cookies work in the different browsers and what you should change to make it work.